# Need help in proving $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \leq x_n \} = \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) < x\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

While solving a problem , I got stuck on the following step: For $A_n = \{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) \leq x_n \}$ where $x_n$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers converging to say, $x$.
I need to show that union of these $A_n$s is equal to the set $ A=\{ \omega \in \Omega | X(\omega) < x \}$.
My attempt has been as follows:.
I first showed that the union is contained in this set by taking an element in the union and using that $x_n < x$.    But now I'm stuck on proving the other inclusion.
Please help.

Comment: If $X(\omega)<x$, set $\varepsilon=x-X(\omega)$. Since $x_n\rightarrow x$, there exists $n$ such that $x-x_n<\varepsilon$, so $X(\omega)<x_n$.

Comment: Little note: for this to be true, $x_n$ must be strictly increasing.

Comment: My stupid question: what is $X(\omega)$?

Comment: @LeAnhDung $X$ is in this context a function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. So for a fixed $\omega\in\Omega$ here $X(\omega)$ is an element of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega\in A$ or equivalently let $X(\omega)<x$.

Then for $n$ large enough we will have $X(\omega)\leq x_n\leq x$ because $x_n$ converges to $x$, so that $x\in A_n$.

(Observe that $x_n<X(\omega)<x$ for every $n$ implies that $x_n$ does *not* converge to $x$ because in that case $x-x_n>x-X(\omega)>0$ for every $n$)

This shows that: $$A\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$

---

Remark: the other inclusion is valid under at least one of the following extra conditions:

- $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=x\}=\varnothing$.
- for every $n$ we have $x_n\neq x$ (hence $x_n<x$ in this context).

The second condition will be satisfied if $x_n$ is [*strictly* increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing). Increasing only is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y<x$. As the sequence converges to $x$ there is an $n$ such that $|x_m-x|<(x-y)$ whenever $m\ge n$. But then $y<x_m$ for all those $m$.